# Win32 C++ Create a Window and Procedure Within a Class

Tags: c++, class, winapi

**Pre-Text/ Question**

I am trying to make a fairly simple tool to help debug variable values. For it to be completely self contained within the class is what I am aiming for. The end product I can use a function in the class like ShowThisValue(whatever).

The problem I am having is that I can't figure out, if possible, to have the procedure within the class. Here is the short version, with the problem.

-Code updated again 11/29/13-
-I have put this in its own project now.

[main.cpp]

```
viewvars TEST; // global
TEST.CreateTestWindow(hThisInstance); // in WinMain() right before ShowWindow(hwnd, nFunsterStil);
```

[viewvars.h] The entire updated

```
class viewvars {

private:
    HWND hWindow;            // the window, a pointer to
    LRESULT WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);        
    static LRESULT CALLBACK ThisWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

public:        
    viewvars(); // blank constructor
    int CreateTestWindow(HINSTANCE hInst);

};

// blank constructor
viewvars::viewvars() {}



// create the window
int viewvars::CreateTestWindow(HINSTANCE hInst) {

// variables
char thisClassName[] = "viewVars";     
MSG msg;       
WNDCLASS wincl;  


// check for class info and modify the info
if (!GetClassInfo(hInst, thisClassName, &wincl)) {
    wincl.style = 0;
    wincl.hInstance = hInst;
    wincl.lpszClassName = thisClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = &ThisWindowProc;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wincl.hIcon = NULL;
    wincl.hCursor = NULL;
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BTNSHADOW;
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;

    if (RegisterClass(&wincl) == 0) {
        MessageBox(NULL,"The window class failed to register.","Error",0); 
        return -1;
    }
}  

// create window
hWindow = CreateWindow(thisClassName, "Test", WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 10, 10, 200, 200, NULL, NULL, hInst, this);
if (hWindow == NULL) { 
    MessageBox(NULL,"Problem creating the window.","Error",0); 
    return -1; 
} 

// show window
ShowWindow(hWindow, TRUE);

// message loop
while (GetMessage(&msg, hWindow, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);  
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
}    

// then quit window?
DestroyWindow(hWindow);
hWindow = NULL;

return msg.wParam;
}   


// window proc
LRESULT CALLBACK viewvars::ThisWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

MessageBox(NULL,"Has it gone this far?","Bench",0); 

// variable
viewvars *view;

// ????
if (message == WM_NCCREATE) {
    CREATESTRUCT *cs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam; 
    view = (viewvars*) cs->lpCreateParams;

    SetLastError(0);
    if (SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) view) == 0) {
        if (GetLastError() != 0) {
            MessageBox(NULL,"There has been an error near here.","Error",0); 
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
else {
    view = (viewvars*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
}


if (view) return view->WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);

MessageBox(NULL,"If shown, the above statement did not return, and the statement below did.","Error",0); 

return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT viewvars::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
// you can access non-static members in here...
MessageBox(NULL,"Made it to window proc.","Error",0);

switch (message)
{
    case WM_PAINT: 
        return 0;
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);       
        return 0;
    break;
    default:
        MessageBox(NULL,"DefWindowProc Returned.","Error",0);
        return DefWindowProc(hWindow, message, wParam, lParam);
    break;
}
}
```

The message boxes appear in this order:

- Has it made it this far?
- Made it to window proc
- DefWindowProc returned
- Has it made it this far? // repeated?
- Made it to window proc
- DefWindowProc returned
- Problem Creating the Window

Thanks for the help so far. Do you know where the problem might be?[image]

Comment: make the windowproc method static.

Comment: It's possible using dynamic thunking technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326813/1768303

Comment: Don't call MessageBox for every message. This creates reentrancy and general confusion. Also, some messages are not expected to yield. Yielding will cause problems.

Comment: True, I just used those messages to see what it was doing. It didn't work in the first place, so I was just seeing what it was doing. As far as this thing goes, it is the equivalent of debugging each step at a time. I could open the console and cout instead of MessageBox, and get the exact same.

Ignore all messages Create Window is not working...

Comment: You didn't set wincl.cbSize.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main message loop must not be in your class, and especially not in a "CreateTestWindow" function, as you will not return from that function until your thread receive the `WM_QUIT` message that makes `GetMessage` returns 0.

Here is simple implementation of your `viewvars` class. Key points:

- The Window Proc is a static member.
- The link between the Window Proc and the object is made through the
  use of GWLP_USERDATA. See [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx).
- The class DTOR destroys the window if it still exists. The WM_DESTROY
  message set the HWND member to 0.
- Adding OnMsgXXX methods to the class is simple: declare/define then
  and just call them from the WindowProc using the 'this' pointer
  stored in GWLP_USERDATA.

**EDIT:**

- As per Mr Chen suggestion, earlier binding of the HWND to the Object (in WM_NCCREATE) to allow message handler as methods *during* the Window Creation.

I changed the creation styles, to show the window and to be able to move it.

```
// VIEWVARS.H
class viewvars {

public:
    static viewvars* CreateTestWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance );
    viewvars() : m_hWnd( 0 ) {}
    ~viewvars();

private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
    static const char * m_pszClassName;
    HWND m_hWnd;

};

// VIEWVARS.CPP
#include "viewvars.h"

const char * viewvars::m_pszClassName = "viewvars";

viewvars * viewvars::CreateTestWindow( HINSTANCE hInst ) {

    WNDCLASS wincl;
    if (!GetClassInfo(hInst, m_pszClassName, &wincl)) {
        wincl.style = 0;
        wincl.hInstance = hInst;
        wincl.lpszClassName = m_pszClassName;
        wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
        wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wincl.hIcon = NULL;
        wincl.hCursor = NULL;
        wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
        wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        if (RegisterClass(&wincl) == 0) {
            MessageBox(NULL,"The window class failed to register.","Error",0);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    viewvars * pviewvars = new viewvars;
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( m_pszClassName, "Test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED, 50, 50, 200, 200, NULL, NULL, hInst, pviewvars );
    if ( hWnd == NULL ) {
        delete pviewvars;
        MessageBox(NULL,"Problem creating the window.","Error",0); 
        return 0; 
    }

    return pviewvars;

}

 LRESULT CALLBACK viewvars::WindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {

    switch ( uMsg ) {

        case WM_NCCREATE: {
            CREATESTRUCT * pcs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            viewvars * pviewvars = (viewvars*)pcs->lpCreateParams;
            pviewvars->m_hWnd = hwnd;
            SetWindowLongPtr( hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)pcs->lpCreateParams );
            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            viewvars * pviewvars = (viewvars *)GetWindowLongPtr( hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA );
            if ( pviewvars ) pviewvars->m_hWnd = 0;
            break;
        }

        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );

    }

    return 0;

}

viewvars::~viewvars() {
    if ( m_hWnd ) DestroyWindow( m_hWnd );
}
```

Finally, a "main" sample, but beware that there is here no way to end the process. That should be taken care by regular code (another windows).

```
// MAIN.CPP
#include <Windows.h>
#include "viewvars.h"

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    viewvars * pviewvars = viewvars::CreateTestWindow( hInstance );
    if ( pviewvars == 0 ) return 0;

    BOOL bRet;
    MSG msg;
    while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 )) != 0)
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            // handle the error and possibly exit
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    }

    delete pviewvars;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Now it makes a bit more sense, that is a working example. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to you. Good luck with the remaining work in "viewvars" :-)

Comment: Note that since you don't set the `GWLP_USERDATA` until after `CreateWindow` returns, this means that you do not get the change to customize the behavior of messages send as part of window creation. Maybe this isn't important, but just calling it out because it may bite you later.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks. Indeed. Updated.

Comment: in WM_NCCREATE message add `SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);` just before `return` to prevent window background flicker on first window appearance.

Answer (score 17):

To use a non-static class method as a window procedure requires a dynamically-allocated thunk, which is an advanced technique that I will not get into it here.

The alternative is to declare the class method as `static`, then it will work as a window procedure.  Of course, being a `static` method, it can no longer access non-static class members without an instance pointer.  To get that pointer, you can have the class pass its `this` pointer to the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()`, then the window procedure can extract that pointer from the `WM_NCCREATE` message and store it in the window using `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_USERDATA)`. After that, subsequent messages can retrieve that pointer using `GetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_USERDATA)` and thus be able to access non-static members of that object.  For example:

```
class viewvars
{
private:
    HWND hWindow;
    LRESULT WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    static LRESULT CALLBACK ThisWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
public:
    int CreateTestWindow(HINSTANCE hInst);
};
```

```
int viewvars::CreateTestWindow(HINSTANCE hInst)
{ 
    WNDCLASS wincl;

    if (!GetClassInfo(hInst, thisClassName, &wincl))
    {
        ...
        wincl.hInstance = hInst;
        wincl.lpszClassName = thisClassName;
        wincl.lpfnWndProc = &ThisWindowProc;

        if (RegisterClass(&wincl) == 0)
            return -1;
    }

    hWindow = CreateWindow(..., hInst, this);
    if (hWindow == NULL)
        return -1;

    ...

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, hWindow, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);  
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }

    DestroyWindow(hWindow);
    hWindow = NULL;

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK viewvars::ThisWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    viewvars *view;

    if (message == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        CREATESTRUCT *cs = (CREATESTRUCT*) lParam; 
        view = (viewvars*) cs->lpCreateParams;

        SetLastError(0);
        if (SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) view) == 0)
        {
            if (GetLastError() != 0)
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        view = (viewvars*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
    }

    if (view)
        return view->WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT viewvars::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // you can access non-static members in here...

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT: 
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);       
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWindow, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 the code i use to frequently do this when using unwrapped (ATL, MFC, WTL, etc..) Windows API windowing code is nearly *identical* to this method, and frankly I'd up-vote this a dozen more times if I could. It bears mentioning the template is slightly different when using a dialog procedure (a different window-long constant, etc) but the premise is still the same. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work.

Right now I am having a problem, though, it gets hung on the registering class part.

My register class paragraph is the same as you posted. Is there anything I need to change or add? I have no previous registration for it.

I have a few questions, too. So where it says access member info, does it mean public/ private variables in the class? what about other functions I add?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you filling out all of the `WNDCLASS` members, not just the few I showed? It is unusual for `RegisterClass()` to hang. And yes, I am referring to all of the class members (variables, methods, etc), public and private, it does not matter (the `static` procedure is itself a member, so it has access to all of them).

Comment: I finished the WNDCLASS members

    `// check for class info and modify the info
    if (!GetClassInfo(hInst, thisClassName, &wincl)) {
        wincl.style = CS_DROPSHADOW;
        wincl.hInstance = hInst;
        wincl.lpszClassName = thisClassName;
        wincl.lpfnWndProc = &ThisWindowProc;
        wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wincl.hIcon = NULL;
        wincl.hCursor = NULL;
        wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BTNSHADOW;
        wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
       
        if (RegisterClass(&wincl) == 0) return -1;
    }  `
-CONTINUED-

Comment: CreateWindow() is now giving me trouble. Any ideas?
   
    `// create window`
    `hWindow = CreateWindow(thisClassName, "Test", WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 10, 10, 200, 200, NULL, NULL, hInst, this);
    if (hWindow == NULL) { MessageBox(0,0,0,0); return -1; }`

Comment: @EvanCarslake: don't put so much code in comments. Please edit your original question instead to show your code. And please explain what trouble you are actually having, what errors are being reported, what steps you have taken to troubleshoot it (have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Have you checked whether WM_NCCREATE is being received before the failure?), etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the original post, WM_NCCREATE is called twice before the failure...

Comment: @EvenCarslake: You should not be getting WM_NCCREATE multiple times on the same window. It is sent only once per window.

Comment: I put some more MessageBox()'s in there. I put it in a new project, and it repeats three items twice; before alerting problem creating the window.

Comment: I made a small change playing around with it. I changed Set/ Get WindowLongPtr, to Set/ Get ClassLongPtr. Now the program looks like it's following code normally and correctly; but now when it gets to the CreateWindow function, it hangs. No runtime errors, doesn't evaluate if hWindow == NULL. I have to close it with the program reset. So... hmm...

Comment: Using `Get/SetClassLongPtr()` is wrong. You need to use `Get/SetWindowLongPtr()` as you need per-HWND storage of the `viewvars*` pointer. That part is working fine, by virtue of the fact that `viewvars::WindowProc()` is being called. `CreateWindow()` sends multiple messages, including `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE`, which is why you see multiple message boxes repeating. You are not reporting which message is being processed. You need to stop calling `MessageBox()` while `CreateWindow()` is busy creating the window. You are altering the normal flow of messages. Use `OutputDebugString()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately using an instance method as a C-style callback function for the WndProc won't work. At least not in any straight-forward way.

The reason it doesn't work like that is that an instance method requires the `this` pointer to be passed in (to point to an instance) and that won't be correctly set by the code calling the WndProc. The Win32 API was originally designed with C in mind so this is one area where you have to use some work-arounds.

One way to work around this would be to create a static method to serve as the window proc and dispatch messages to your class instances. The class instances would have to be registered (read added to a static collection) so the static method would know to dispatch WndProc messages to the instances. Instances would register themselves with the static dispatcher in the constructor and remove themselves in the destructor.

Of course all the registration and unregistration and dispatching overhead is only necessary if your WndProc handler needs to invoke other instance member functions, or access member variables. Otherwise you can just make it static and you're done.

Comment: You do not need a static collection to hold the class instance pointers. When the class creates its window, it can pass its `this` pointer to the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()`, then the window procedure can extract that pointer from the `WM_NCCREATE` message and store it in the window using `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_USERDATA)`. After that, subsequent messages can retrieve that pointer using `GetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_USERDATA)` and call non-static methods on it as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - good point! It's been a while since I've had to deal with this problem so I was mostly going off of old memories

Answer (score 2):

Your window procedure is called during CreateWindow. You pass hWindow to DefWindowProc, but hWindow is only set after CreateWindow returns - so you pass DefWindowProc a garbage window handle.

I don't see a nice way to do it. You could set hWindow inside the window procedure, by changing WindowProc to:

```
LRESULT WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

(added the hwnd parameter), changing the call to:

```
return view->WindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

creating the window like this:

```
hWindow = NULL;
hWindow = CreateWindow(..., hInst, this);
if (hWindow == NULL)
    return -1;
```

(the first assignment is to make sure hWindow is initialized; the second one is in case CreateWindow fails after calling the window procedure), and adding this at the start of WindowProc:

```
if(!this->hWindow)
    this->hWindow = hwnd;
```

Comment: You're right, that seems to be the problem. I looked thoroughly threw it, and couldn't find anywhere where I could set the hWindow.
 
Any idea of where I could set it? 

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a nice solution either. Perhaps pass the HWND as the first argument to WindowProc. (this would be redundant once hWindow is initialized).

Comment: I tried it, and it ended up giving me errors because of the static. I am beginning to think that if this can be done, it is barely possible. I also looked at a (10 year old) C wrapper class for Win32, and ended up having endless memory leaks (as users described). The code was semi-similar to what I have. Hmm...

Comment: I updated my answer with the code changes needed for my solution.

Comment: Thanks, Ive got/had it semi-working. At first the window would come up but would go into some sort of infinite loop, whole window and close buttons flickered.

Anyways, now I am having trouble executing the function. In the main file, nothing passes the CreateWindow()/ ShowWindow() for the main window.

    `hwnd = CreateWindowEx (0, szClassName, "Windows App", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, ...,  HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);`
      

    `ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);  `


    `TEST.CreateTestWindow(hThisInstance); `

The main window displays, never makes it to TEST.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: I think that creating both windows is likely to be the last problem. I added a picture to show exactly what I am trying to do. I can only get 1 window displayed (either or,) and when I close it, the program ends.

Answer (score -1):

Step through the code in the debugger. When you get to the line

```
    MessageBox(NULL,"DefWindowProc Returned.","Error",0);
    return DefWindowProc(hWindow, message, wParam, lParam);
```

You will see something wrong: `hWindow` is garbage. You are using an uninitialized variable.