# C++ Win32 Control Procedure within a Class

Tags: c++, winapi, stored-procedures

What I am trying to do, is to create a edit control and procedure within a class. I have tried various things, and tried using parts of a similar question I asked: [Win32 C++ Create a Window and Procedure Within a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256436/win32-c-create-a-window-and-procedure-within-a-class/).

At the moment, I took them apart.

```
main_class.h

class MainClass {

private:
    HWND hwndMain; // main windows handle
    HINSTANCE hInstanceMain; // main windows instance
    HWND hTextarea;

public:
    bool init(HWND _hwnd, HINSTANCE _hInstance);
    bool ShowInfoTextarea();
};



main_class.cpp
// Heres the question
bool MainClass::ShowInfoTextarea() {

    if (hTextarea != NULL) return true; // if it is not null, the textarea is likely already displayed.

    // Creating the EDIT textarea
    hTextarea = CreateWindowEx(0, L"EDIT", L"", 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 
        SCREEN_WIDTH+5, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH-SCREEN_WIDTH-10, WINDOW_HEIGHT-30, hwndMain, (HMENU)IDC_CTRL_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    if (hTextarea == NULL) { MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not create the test text control. The program will now close.", NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); return false; }

    // Dozens of attempts with something like:
    // lpEditWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hTextarea, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)EditControlProc); 
    // lpEditWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hTextarea, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)MainClass::EditControlProc);
    // tried static callback functions, etc.

    //Every try the compiler said: Are there missing braces ( ) with EditControlProc

}


// To get working, I separated:
    WNDPROC lpEditWndProc;        
    LRESULT CALLBACK EditControlProc(HWND hwndEdit, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

        switch (uMsg) {
            default:
                return CallWindowProc(lpEditWndProc, hwndEdit, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 

        }

        return 0; // DONE
    }
```

With my (various) attempts the compiler said: Are there missing braces ( ) with EditControlProc, or said type mismatch when trying to define lpEditWndProc.

I am probably missing out on something simple?

Useage:

```
main.cpp
MainClass mainclass;
mainclass.ShowInfoTextarea();
```

Thanks. If missing any info let me know.

Comment: Is `EditControlProc` a class member function? If so it needs to be declared as `static`. Also look at using `SetWindowSubclass` rather than `SetWindowLongPtr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan Potter's comment was the solution.

For anyone who reads:

```
 mainclass.h

class MainClass {

    private:
        HWND hwndMain;
        HINSTANCE hInstanceMain;
        HWND hTextarea;
        static LRESULT CALLBACK EditControlProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
    public:
        bool init(HWND _hwnd, HINSTANCE _hInstance);
        bool ShowInfoTextarea();


};



mainclass.cpp

// To Show the Textarea
bool MainClass::ShowInfoTextarea() {

    if (hTextarea != NULL) return true; // if it is not null, the textarea is likely already displayed.

    // Creating the EDIT textarea
    hTextarea = CreateWindowEx(0, L"EDIT", L"", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 
    SCREEN_WIDTH+5, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH-SCREEN_WIDTH-10, WINDOW_HEIGHT-30, hwndMain, (HMENU)IDC_CTRL_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

        if (hTextarea == NULL) { MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not create the test text control. The program will now close.", NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); return false; }

    SetWindowSubclass(hTextarea, EditControlProc, 0, 0);

}


// Now Works
LRESULT CALLBACK MainClass::EditControlProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {

    switch (msg) {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0; // DONE
}
```