# Encapsulate Win32 in a class - pass class pointer in CreateWindow

Tags: windows, winapi

I viewed many tutorials and posts on this subject, and they all say I pass the class instance pointer (`this`) in my `CreateWindowEx()` function, and then store it in the window procedure function, when the `WM_NCCREATE` message is sent. I guess this is because `WM_NCCREATE` is supposedly the first message that gets sent to the window procedure since a window is created.

A few questions/notes:

1. From debugging I came to know that actually `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` is the first sent message, *before* `WM_NCCREATE` (at least on my machine). Does this mean I should listen for this message instead of `WM_NCCREATE`?
2. According to [this](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/creating-a-win32-window-wrapper-class-r1810) popular article, the reason everyone calls `SetWindowLongPtr()` after the message `WM_NCCREATE` is received is because

   > If the value does not exist by the time WM_NCCREATE is called then,
   >   by some mysterious Windows behavior that I still don't understand, the
   >   value never gets inserted.

I tried to do exactly that (that is, call `SetWindowLongPtr()` after `CreateWindowEx()`). It turns out to be just fine. The application runs okay. Below is my code, please tell me if there's something wrong with this approach.

```
void GLWin32::CreateWindow(...)
{
    ...

    _hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, _wndclassex.lpszClassName, title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, x, y, width, height, NULL, NULL, _hinstance, NULL);
    SetWindowLongPtr(_hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(this));

    ...
}

//static window procedure for all instances of this class
LRESULT CALLBACK GLWin32::_msgRouter(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    LONG l = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    GLWin32* thisPtr = reinterpret_cast<GLWin32*>(l);

    if (thisPtr)
        return thisPtr->_winProc(msg, wparam, lparam);
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

LRESULT GLWin32::_winProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(_hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Why is my approach not used instead of the [popular approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256795/4266765)?

Comment: "*Does this mean I should listen for [WM_GETMINMAXINFO] instead of WM_NCCREATE?*" `WM_NCCREATE` is the first message received that gives you access to the `lpParam` value you pass to `CreateWindowEx()`.

Comment: The most robust solution is to set a local [CBT Hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx), calling [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx). The hook procedure is called before any message is sent to the window procedure, and is immune to message reordering. Incidentally, that's what MFC uses. I don't know what makes the second-best option popular, though.

Comment: If you don't need any custom processing for any messages received before `CreateWindowEx` returns, there's nothing wrong with your approach. If you do - there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that if you want to use the instance when processing any of the window creation messages (including "ordinary" messages that are sent as part of the creation process), you won't have access to it.

Suppose you want to create a button when processing *WM_CREATE* (typical scenario) and you want to set the button text to some instance member value. You want something like:

```
LRESULT GLWin32::_winProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateWindow("BUTTON", this->buttonText, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
          10, 10, 50, 30, this->hwnd, NULL, this->hInstance, NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(_hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Problem is, when *WM_CREATE* is processed (before `CreateWindowEx` returns), `SetWindowLongPtr` wasn't called yet and the instance pointer is missing, so `_winProc` isn't being called at all.

Comment: During creation, the instance pointer arrives only in the `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE` messages. Until the window procedure receives one of those messages, the instance pointer is not accessible and cannot be stored in the HWND for subsequent access. Unless you store the pointer in a global, or thread-local, variable before calling `CreateWindowsEx()`, then you can use+store it in the HWND on the very first message received.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I don't understand the context of your comment. It's correct of course, but doesn't really address anything in my answer. Care to explain?

Comment: "*The problem with this approach is that if you want to use the instance when processing any of the window creation messages (including "ordinary" messages that are sent as part of the creation process), you won't have access to it.*" I was simply stating that there are 2 creation messages that provide access to the instance pointer passed to `CreateWindowEx()`.

Comment: @Amit So if I don't care about the `WM_CREATE`, my approach is fine?

Comment: I mean, if I don't want any extra code to work before the window is created.

Comment: @Pilpel - you'll risk missing other messages as well such as WM_SIZE, WM_MOVE or others that might get sent between `CreateWindowEx` & `SetWindowLongPtr`, but more importantly, if you already know an advantageous  pattern, why do anything else?

Comment: A mix of laziness and the will for a cleaner code. But you're right.

Comment: Can you still try to explain the quote I gave from the gamedev article?

Comment: @Pilpel - I don't know what it means and I doubt there are any mysteries in Windows' window creation process.

Comment: @Pilpel: I would assume, that the gamedev.net-quote you posted relates to messages getting added or reordered (in different versions of Windows), rendering code that relies on a particular sequence of messages useless. A solution that does not rely on this exists. When I find the time I'll wrap it up in an answer.