# Why is this call to CreateWindow failing, and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I'm following a tutorial for directx12 and can't even get over the creation of window D: There is an implemented error window which tells me that there was an error when creating the window i actually want to create. 
It's supposed to mean that it was "unsuccessful in getting a window handle"...
I don't have anything as much as a clue of what that would mean but i would GREATLY appreciate some help about that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

//Handle to the window
HWND hwnd = NULL;

//Name of the window
LPCTSTR WindowName = L"GameEngineApp";

//Title of the window
LPCTSTR WindowTitle = L"My Game Engine";

//Width and height of the window
int Width = 800;
int Height = 600;

//Toggle for fool screen
bool FullScreen = false;

//Toggle for window creation
bool InitializeWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    int ShowWnd, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

//Main application loop
void mainLoop()
{
    //The message var hold any windows message received through the 
    //PeekMessage function
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));

    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            //If there is a message, it is translated
            //then dispatched so Windows 
            //knows the program hasn't stopped working
            if (msg.message = WM_QUIT) {
                break;

                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
            else {
                //If there is no message the game 
                //code will run and the loop will continue
            }
        }
    }
}

//Callback function for windows messages
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,
    UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) {
            if (MessageBox(0, L"Are you sure you want to exit?",
                L"Really?", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,
        msg, wParam, lParam);
}

//Main Windows function
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nShowCmd)
{
    //Toggle window creation
    if (!InitializeWindow(hInstance, nShowCmd, Width, Height, FullScreen))
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Window Initialization - Failed",
            L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    mainLoop(); //Call main loop to start

    return 0;
}

bool InitializeWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    int ShowWnd, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{
    //Check if fullscreen is needed and set to fullscreen if so
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        HMONITOR hmon = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd,
            MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
        MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) };
        GetMonitorInfo(hmon, &mi);

        width = mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left;
        height = mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top;
    }

    //Window class structure
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = WindowName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    //Registering the window class
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error registering class",
            L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }

    //Create the window with the now registered window class
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        WindowName,
        WindowTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        width, height,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    //Return error msg if unsuccessful in getting a window handle
    if (!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error creating window",
            L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }

    //Removing the style from the window when fullscreen
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, 0);
    }

    //Showing and updating the window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, ShowWnd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    return true;
}
```

I've tried to change CreateWIndowEx to CreateWindowA and that's really the only thing that seemed to possibly have an effect but i did not see any results.
I've tried printing the error but there is no error.

Creating a window in Windows with the C++ code so i can make a game engine.

Comment: Please include your code, without a [mcve] it's going to be difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! and sorry i was working on it because i could figure out how to indent it in my text box.

Comment: Your message loop is off. You probably meant to break on WM_QUIT, but you only process the message if it's WM_QUIT. Fix the braces.

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Comment: You want `msg.message == WM_QUIT` at minimum.

Comment: Same reason as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20308924/902497 - you are passing an uninitialized variable to `DefWindowProc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though shalt not abuse global variables.

You're calling `DefWndProc` in your `WndProc` with `hwnd` as the handle argument. But that isn't set until the return of `CreateWindowEx`, and there are plenty *very* important messages that are rifled through `WndProc` during window stand-up. Those messages need the window handle, and you're not passing it along. Instead you're just passing `NULL` (the startup value of `hwnd`).

Change **all** `hwnd` to `hWnd` (the parameter name) in your `WndProc`

The remainder of the problems mentioned in comments I leave for you to address.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, that actually worked out! I really didn't figure out i had a typo in an if statement which is pretty bad but now i have to end the process in task manager for it to close and i don't know if that's normal because i believe i have implemented a function to close the window.